# How to find the number of lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

How to find the number of increasing lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that never cross but may touch the main diagonal (for example the line joining $(0,0)$ with $(n,n)$).
I've found a similar question here (I did not manage to find it again) but I guess this case is a little different (because the final answer is $2c_n$, however in the question I saw it was $c_n$).
Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_n$ counts the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ which *always remain at or below* the main diagonal, but never above.  Equivalently, $C_n$ counts the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ which always remain at or *above* the main diagonal but never below.  If you don't mind whether the path stays at or above always or at or below always, then add the two totals together to find the total number of paths which never cross the main diagonal but who may have stayed at or above or at or below, $2C_n$.

Answer (score 1):

JMoravitz's comment answers this.  Turning that into an answer for completeness:

The [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof) count various things including paths which stay on or *below* the diagonal (i.e. do not go above it): a [previous question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376522/monotonic-lattice-paths-and-catalan-numbers) asked for a proof.

The number of paths which stay on or *above* the diagonal is clearly the same number, and for $n \ge 1$ a path must go above or below the diagonal at the start so the combined number of paths which do not cross the diagonal is double the Catalan numbers.

[OEIS A068875](https://oeis.org/A068875) gives the values for small $n$.